# Trouble loading images from jar file for GWT project

Tags: java, image, gwt, import, jar

Currently I have exported my GWT project as a jar and tried to use it in another project. However,
the images are not loading up. This is the tab bar where the images i put, which is an X does not show up, but instead the deafult error picture shows up.

[image]

Here is my code for the loading the X's as the default images.

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <ui:style>
    </ui:style>
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <g:HorizontalPanel>
            <g:Image width="19px" url="mvpwebapp/gwt/clean/images/xmark.png" ui:field="checkimage"></g:Image>
            <g:Label text="ClickMe" ui:field="label_one"/>
            <g:Image width="19px" url="mvpwebapp/gwt/clean/images/xmark.png" ui:field="label2_image"/>
            <g:Label text="Button 2" ui:field="label_2"/>
            <g:Image width="19px" url="mvpwebapp/gwt/clean/images/xmark.png" ui:field="label3_image"/>
            <g:Label text="Button 3" ui:field="label_3"/>
            <g:Image width="19px" url="mvpwebapp/gwt/clean/images/xmark.png"     ui:field="label4_image"></g:Image>
            <g:Label text="Button4" ui:field="label_4"/>
        </g:HorizontalPanel>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

I get `[Warn] 404` whenever it tries to get the image.

Thank You for your help!

Comment: fixed this issue by adding my image folder into my new project. It seems like it does not get imported correctly, so it searches for the new url in the new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this issue by adding my image folder into my new project. It seems like it does not get imported correctly, so it searches for the new url in the new project.